# Change thread priority ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE

Tags: multithreading, perl, winapi, thread-priority

I'm trying to change a thread priority within my script, without success, here are the details.

```
$thr = threads->new(\&someFunction, 
                    $shared variable 1,
                    $shared variable 2, 
                   );
```

I've tried using `threads::State`;

```
$thr->priority(2);
```

Without success

So, I thought the `Win32::API` must work

```
my $functionGetLastError= Win32::API->new('Kernel32', 
                                          'GetLastError',
                                          '', 
                                          'N'
                                       );
my $functionSetThreadPriority= Win32::API->new('Kernel32', 
                                               'SetThreadPriority',
                                               'II', # I've tried 'PI' and 'II' as well
                                               'N'
                                              );
my $h = $thr->_handle();
my $success = $functionSetThreadPriority->Call( $h, 2 );
warn "Return Error #".$functionGetLastError->Call() if !$success;
```

Again, without success: (, but now I have a clue, the script return error number

> last Error 6

From [MSDN site, System Error Codes (0-499)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), it seems that the error is

> ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See [What kind of threads are Perl threads?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlthrtut.html#What-kind-of-threads-are-Perl-threads%3f) in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$thread->_handle` weirdly returns a `HANDLE*`, while `SetThreadPriority` expects a `HANDLE`. You need to dereference the pointer, which you can do as follows:

```
use constant THREAD_PRIORITY_HIGHEST => 2;

sub SetThreadPriority {
   my ($thread, $priority) = @_;

   # $thread->_handle() returns a HANDLE*.
   my $handle_ptr    = $thread->_handle();
   my $packed_handle = unpack('P'.HANDLE_SIZE, pack(PTR_FORMAT, $handle_ptr));
   my $handle        = unpack(HANDLE_FORMAT, $packed_handle);

   state $SetThreadPriority = (
      Win32::API->new('Kernel32', 'SetThreadPriority', 'Ni', 'i')
         or die("Loading SetThreadPriority: $^E\n")
   );

   return $SetThreadPriority->Call($handle, $priority);
}
```

---

Here's the full test program:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say state );

use threads;
use threads::shared;

use Carp       qw( croak );
use Config     qw( %Config );
use Win32::API qw( );

sub uint_format {
     $_[0] == 4 ? 'L'
   : $_[0] == 8 ? 'Q'
   : croak("Unsupported")
}

use constant PTR_SIZE   => $Config{ptrsize};
use constant PTR_FORMAT => uint_format(PTR_SIZE);

use constant HANDLE_SIZE   => PTR_SIZE;
use constant HANDLE_FORMAT => PTR_FORMAT;

use constant THREAD_PRIORITY_HIGHEST => 2;

sub SetThreadPriority {
   my ($thread, $priority) = @_;

   # $thread->_handle() returns a HANDLE*.
   my $handle_ptr    = $thread->_handle();
   my $packed_handle = unpack('P'.HANDLE_SIZE, pack(PTR_FORMAT, $handle_ptr));
   my $handle        = unpack(HANDLE_FORMAT, $packed_handle);

   state $SetThreadPriority = (
      Win32::API->new('Kernel32', 'SetThreadPriority', 'Ni', 'i')
         or die("Loading SetThreadPriority: $^E\n")
   );

   return $SetThreadPriority->Call($handle, $priority);
}

{
   my $done :shared = 0;

   my $thread = async {
      { lock($done); cond_wait($done) while !$done; }
   };

   my $rv = SetThreadPriority($thread, THREAD_PRIORITY_HIGHEST);
   say $rv ? "Success" : "Error: $^E";

   { lock($done); $done = 1; cond_broadcast($done); }
   $thread->join();
}
```

---

Notice that you can use `$^E` to access `GetLastError`.

```
SetThreadPriority($handle, THREAD_PRIORITY_HIGHEST)
   or die("SetThreadPriority: $^E\n";
```

Comment: I would say that is a bug, but odds are that can't be changed anymore at this stage. Not the first of that kind in threads.pm :-/

Answer (score 0):

> ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE

Which suggests that what _handle returns is not something Win32::API understands. I suspect "P" wants a string buffer not an integer-casted pointer. "I" may be the wrong thing because it's the wrong size on 64-bit, I would try "N" myself.

Also, for future readers running into this issue on Unix: try my [POSIX::RT::Scheduler](https://metacpan.org/pod/POSIX::RT::Scheduler) module.

Comment: `N` what Win32::API documents as an integer equivalent of a pointer. The real problem, though, is that `_handle` returns a `HANDLE*`, but `SetThreadPriority` expects a `HANDLE`.

Comment: I have tried to compile POSIX::RT::Scheduler, without success :(